# Transition from Wait queue to run queue

Tags: linux, kernel, sleep

When a process calls wait_event_interruptible the process goes to sleep(assuming the condition is satisfied and there are no pending signals) the scheduler removes the process from the run queue to the wait queue.
When there is wake_up call how exactly and who removes the process from wait queue and keeps it in the run queue?

Thaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "wake_up call" is a *system call* done by another thread/process/task (some kernels put state on thread rather than process) with the thread/process/task to wake up in parameter. Because the *system call* is an interrupt (`int $0x80` on Linux, until it was recently replaced by `sysenter` which is basically the same), thus entering the kernel, the scheduler will be called and the requested thred/process/task will be poped out the blocked queue and pushed into the ready queue. If this thread/process/task has the highest priority, it will eventually run when returning from the interrupt, therefore going directly from the blocked state to the running state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) . So you mean to say again its the scheduler which removes a process from wait queue and puts it in the ready queue?

Comment: The sched_add()/sched_remove() functions of the scheduler module are called inside the syscall (i.e. during the syscall interrupt). These functions will internally add and remove the thread from the relevants scheduling data structures. Therefore you can consider it's the scheduler module which does the work, but it's the user who trigger this by making a syscall (the "wake_up call").

Comment: Thanks :) Can you please help me find the functions sched_add/sched_remove in the kernel tree. From which version of kernel onwards are these functions included?

Comment: These functions are heavily dependant on the version of the scheduler you are using. For instance, for a 2.6.36, you could check the `enqueue_task()` inside _kernel/sched.c_ which enqueue a task into the active runqueue.